# How long does it take to get a Denmark visa from VFS Global in San Francisco?

Tags: indian-citizens, denmark, us-residents, vfs-global

I am an Indian citizen, living in San Francisco. I intend to fly to Denmark on the 18th of May.

However, the earliest appointment available is 14th of May at VFS Global in San Francisco. Is this too short of a timeline? Do I have to postpone/cancel my trip?

Comment: Have you requested the premium service?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Denmark in the USA](http://usa.um.dk/en/travel-and-residence/visa/tourist-business-and-transit/) advises:

> Normal processing time for a visa application is 15 calendar days. However, please note that processing times depend on case volume. Expect longer processing times in May, June, July, August and December due to peak season travel.
>
> A visa application can be launched as early as 3 months prior to the arrival date in Schengen, and it is strongly recommended that an application be launched no later than 20-30 days prior to departure. Here is why:
>
> 1. It can take up to 14 days to obtain an appointment with VFS Global for submitting your application.
> 2. Case processing does not begin until the application arrives at the Consulate General of Denmark in New York. Hence, your application is not launched when you apply online, or when you have your appointment with VFS Global. The shipping of your documents to and from the Consulate General of Denmark in New York adds 2-4 days to the processing time.
> 3. An application lodged less than 15 calendar days before the intended departure may be accepted at VFS, but the final decision might be taken after the date of departure.